# Missing graph data in python using sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am working on a Student Management System which basically does CURD operations and displays bar charts of students vs scores. I have searched about how to plot graph using data from database and tried to code the thing with my parameters. But I cant seem to get the data into the graph the axes were made though!
Can I get some pointers on how I should change my code.

**Here is the code I wrote:**

```
        charts_window.deiconify()
        main.withdraw()
        con = None
        try:
            con = connect('omkar.db')
            cursor = con.cursor()
            def graph():
                cursor.execute("SELECT name , marks FROM student")
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                students = []
                scores = []
                for d in data:
                    students.append(d[0])
                    scores.append(d[1])

                plt.bar('students','scores',color = ['red','green'])
                plt.xlabel("students")
                plt.ylabel("scores")
                plt.title('Results')
            
                plt.show()
                con.commit()
            graph()
        except Exception as e:
            showerror('ERROR',e)
            
        finally:
            if con is not None:
                con.close()
```

**Here is how the chart screen is appearing:**

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omWa0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
plt.bar('students','scores',color = ['red','green'])
```

Are the students and scores parameters supposed to be strings? Try:

```
plt.bar(students, scores, color = ['red', 'green'])
```

Comment: Your answer is much appreciated. The error was solved

Comment: sry i am new here